# Netbeans as Mercurial Merge Tool

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, merge, diff

the company I work for have started to use Mercurial as our version control software, with NetBeans becoming the editor of choice for most developers.

Up until now we've been using WinMerge and KDiff3as our Mercurial merge tool, but have decided that we don't like it.

Now one of the things we've noticed about NetBeans is that it has a very nice diff tool built into it, so was hoping that there might be some way of using this as the Mercurial merge tool?

Can anyone let me know if this is possible, and if so, how?

(Or, are there any other windows diff/merge tools that are as good as the NetBeans diff tool?)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using the NetBeans diff tool but as for other merge tools that will work well with Mercurial, I would recommend [Perforce's Merge tool](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html) which I have heard is somewhat similar to the Netbeans one.

Another good one is [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've played with NetBeans a bit more, and now understand it's own merge tool (different to its diff tool) - but even this has some minor issues.

Anyway, I'll give your suggestions a try :)

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, there is no way to call Netbean's diff/merge tool from the command line, which is necessary to use it from Mercurial.

FWIW: I use Beyond Compare 3 for all of my diff / merge activities, even though I use Netbeans as a primary editor, and it does have Mercurial integration.

Functionally, I find the Beyond Compare interface to be a little easier, and it comes with a number of other features that I didn't think I needed, but have since grown completely dependent on, such as performing text diffs on entire folders, image diffs, and pushing changes between files that are being diffed.